# Docker command failing with sh not found error

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using docker to build an image an run. The image is getting built correctly, but, when I run, the sh command is not found. I am getting the error `/bin/sh: ./run.sh: not found`.

I am running the docker using `docker compose`

```
version: '2'
services:
  licensingservice:
      image: johncarnell/tmx-licensing-service:chapter2
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
```

The below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN  apk update && apk upgrade && apk add netcat-openbsd
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/licensingservice
ADD  @project.build.finalName@.jar /usr/local/licensingservice/
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

The run.sh command is inside the same folder where the `Dockerfile` is present.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "********************************************************"
echo "Starting License Server"
echo "********************************************************"
java -jar /usr/local/licensing-service/@project.build.finalName@.jar
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you start a shell (`docker run <yourimage> sh`) and examine the container, is `run.sh` where you expect to find it? Are you able to run it by hand?

Comment: When I run ` docker run dfb6e9b372f6 sh`, there is no error and nothing happens.
    docker run dfb6e9b372f6 sh docker run dfb6e9b372f6 sh

Comment: When  I run the docker run <imageid> sh run.sh ,its working fine.

E:\spring-cloud-microservices\spmia-chapter2 (master -> origin)
λ docker run  7bff05f66ba8 sh run.sh
********************************************************
Starting License Server
********************************************************

Comment: `/bin/sh: ./run.sh: not found` how you run container when you get this error?

Comment: I ran using the `docker-compose up` command

    `version: '2'
    services:
      licensingservice:
          image: johncarnell/tmx-licensing-service:chapter2
          ports:
            - "8080:8080"
         `

Comment: if you are running with docker-compose please post the docker-compose too.

Comment: updated the docker compose file in the question.

Comment: docker-compose seems fine, the only that can be the reason is name of image, can you try with `image: 7bff05f66ba8` or docker `build -t johncarnell/tmx-licensing-service:chapter2 . `  then `image:johncarnell/tmx-licensing-service:chapter2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202084/discussion-between-zilcuanu-and-adiii).